# Problem with "No matching constructor for initialization of 'LM35' in "main.cpp", Line: 16, Col: 27"

Tags: c++, embedded, mbed

I'm a student, learning about MBEDs. I'm using Nucleo board and the MBED online compiler.
Here's my code:

LM35.h

```
#ifndef MBED_LM35
#define MBED_LM35
#include "mbed.h"

class LM35
{
    public:
        LM35(PinName pin);
        void mjerenje();
        
    private:
        AnalogIn _pin;
};
    
#endif
```

LM35.cpp

```
#include "LM35.h"
#include "mbed.h"

LM35::LM35(PinName pin) : _pin(pin) {}
    
float temperatura;
    
void LM35::mjerenje()
{
    Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
    
    temperatura = _pin.read();
    temperatura = (temperatura*5000)/10;
    pc.printf("Temperatura je %.2f stupnjeva Celzijevih.\n \r", temperatura);
    return temperatura;
}
```

and here's Main.cpp

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "LM35.h"
    
DigitalOut led1(PC_12);
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
LM35 senzor(PC_0);
    
int main()
{
    senzor.mjerenje();
         
    float temperatura2 = LM35();
    pc.printf("%f", temperatura2);
}
```

I'm having trouble with getting temperatura out of library and using it in main.cpp.
I get following error: Error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'LM35' in "main.cpp", Line: 16, Col: 27

Can someone help me?

Comment: Well, so what's going on in `= LM35();`? To which pin should `LM35()` be connected?

Comment: No no, I need to get the "temperatura" float value from LM35.cpp to be usable in main

Comment: `temperatura` isn't a member of `LM35`, `LM35()` is attempting to create a new instance of `LM35` not trying to retrieve any value from the existing `senzor` instance

Comment: So this "return temperatura;" goes where exactly? How can I reach that return value?

Comment: The main.cpp you have posted does not have 16 lines.  It is helpful to post the exact code being compiled, or at least to indicate which line it is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in LM35.cpp

```
void LM35::mjerenje()
```

return a float value, should be -->

```
float LM35::mjerenje()
```

in the main.cpp

```
 float temperatura2;
 temperatura2 = senzor.mjerenje();
```

Comment: It says: Error: Assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'void' in "main.cpp", Line: 17, Col: 27

Comment: you need to change `void mjerenje()` in the header to `float mjerenje()` too.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot! :)